# Saving ARCore Image Database between sessions

Tags: android, arcore

first time posting.

I’m trying to save an augmented image database made during runtime, for using in a later session. I have looked around but found no questions related to this.

Thanks in advance.

*EDIT* should have mentioned, I am using Unity(sorry, I'm new).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use serialize function to create a byte array or an output stream depending on whether you use Android or Android NDK.

For NDK:

```
void ArAugmentedImageDatabase_serialize(
      const ArSession *session,
      const ArAugmentedImageDatabase *augmented_image_database,
      uint8_t **out_image_database_raw_bytes,
      int64_t *out_image_database_raw_bytes_size
    )
```

For Android:

```
public void serialize (OutputStream outputStream)
```

For Unity: First you have to import your image and in import settings you should check Read/Write Enabled.
Then, you have to convert your image to either RGBA32 or RGB24. Because ARCore only supports these two formats.

```
        Texture2D empty = new Texture2D(ImportedImage.width,ImportedImage.height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
        empty.SetPixels(ImportedImage.GetPixels());
        empty.Apply();
```

Then you can use `databaseTest.AddImage("first",empty);` However, this database has to be used in your ARCoreSessionConfig Augmented Image Database field like this:

[image]

Otherwise app hangs i am not sure why. Good luck!

Comment: hey, thanks @alikanat for the quick answer, I'm on Unity, is it possible on there?

Comment: I am not sure about unity. In theory it should be possible but can you add the code how you created an augmented image database during runtime?

Comment: `void Start()
        {
        augmentedImageDatabase = new AugmentedImageDatabase();
        SessionConfig.AugmentedImageDatabase = augmentedImageDatabase; `

and then further down

   `  foreach (Texture2D tex in preDBTex)
        {
            augmentedImageDatabase.AddImage(tex.name, tex);
        }  `
that's pretty much the jist of it. Create the new database at launch then add the images once they have all  downloaded. I'm looking to not have to download and/or create a new database each time.

Comment: The only workaround i found is creating a database on the project view. In your script `public AugmentedImageDatabase database` drug it to your script and remove all the images in it, at start using `database.remove(int index)` then i believe you should be able to add images. I cant add now because ARCore has a bug but please give it a try.  This is the [bug](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/issues/403) i am getting.

Comment: Instant Preview is doing this for me as well. I have only been able to build out and work from there each time. A real pain.

Comment: I dig a lot into api but i dont think there is a way to serialize a database in unity. But as i said before what you can do is just create a database in project view, empty it and add your images to that database. Then you can use it in other sessions. Probably, that is the reason why there is not a serialize function in Unity because you can create them in project view and alter.

Comment: Thanks @ali, just to check and clarify for me, can you create the database in the editor, then add images in runtime on the app and have them persist as part of the database between sessions.

Comment: Apparently it is possible i have not able to added images yet. But i can delete images and this persist between sessions. Apparently not all image formats are supported only RGB24 and RGBA32 are supported. Also Also textures need to have read/write checkbox enabled. For more info please refer [here](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/issues/256)

Comment: Cool, I have tried the upvoting thing for your answer, and marked it as correct as I think this covers how to do it pretty completely.

Comment: Thanks i am still working on it. If i find a working solution for adding images i will edit the answer.