# Can't add images to AugmentedImageDatabase in ARCore

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arcore

I'm writing an application in unity. In the future I need to be able to pull images from the web and use them as trackers, so I'm currently writing code that adds images from a list to the AugmentedImageDatabase at runtime.

Every time I add an image however, the `AugmentedImageDatabase.AddImage()` method returns a -1. This means there was an error adding the image, but it doesn't say what kind of error. I've checked the API docs, but they don't add any information either.

Why doesn't my code add images to the AugmentedImageDatabase?

```
public class DataBaseGenerator : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField]
    ARCoreSessionConfig session;

    [SerializeField]
    AugmentedImageDatabase imageDatabase;

    [SerializeField]
    List<Texture2D> image;

    private int ErrorIndex = 0;

    // What happens on the first frame
    void Start ()
    {
        CreateDatabase();
    }
    private void CreateDatabase()
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Texture2D texture in image)
        {
            string name = "Tracker";
            Texture2D rgbTexture = new Texture2D(texture.width, texture.height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
            rgbTexture.SetPixels(texture.GetPixels());
            rgbTexture.Apply();

            ErrorIndex = imageDatabase.AddImage(name, rgbTexture, 0);
            GameUtility.ShowToastMessage(ErrorIndex.ToString());
            Debug.Log(name + ": " + ErrorIndex);
            i++;
        }
        session.AugmentedImageDatabase = imageDatabase;
    }
}
```

All the images in the list have been saved as Sprites.
All variables with the `[SerializeField]` tag are defined in the unity editor.

Comment: What is the format of your texture. ARCore only supports two formats. You can take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52970270/saving-arcore-image-database-between-sessions/52971643#52971643)

Comment: Tried changing the format to rgb32, still doesn't work. Using a .png file extension, which is supported.

Comment: Well as far as i see from the code error `-1` is the case when your `nativeSession == null`. Are you trying to add images in an ARCore session?

Comment: @AliKanat I pass the ARCoreSession-file to `session` variable at the top of the code snippet. This is the same session that is passed to the camera. I also have an AugmentedImageDatabase, "DB" that is loaded into `imageDatabase`. Then at the end, I do `session.AugmentedImageDatabase = imageDatabase`

Comment: Another reason can be you start the coroutine in `Start` but probably at that stage Session is just initializing. Try to do this with a touch after Session is initialized. You can check `Session.Status` for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since OP did not reply back i am assuming my comment solved the problem and converting my comment to an answer.

ARCore only supports two texture formats(RGBA32 or RGB24) for `Augmented Image Database`. Therefore, the texture have to be converted first in order to be able to add images to database.

Second problem in OP's code was he was trying to add images to database in `Start` which obviously gets executed when the application is started. Therefore, the session status is either `None` or `Initializing` which results in `LifecycleManager.Instance.NativeSession` returning null. Since there is no `Session` at the moment you can not add images to the Database.

Comment: Indeed, this error is solved. You can use `private void OnEnable() { LifecycleManager.Instance.EarlyUpdate += CreateDatabase }` to perform the action when the Session is in effect, but I am now getting a different error which could be caused this way.